# How to find and install missing dependencies of SpringSource for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, springsource

I wanted to install SpringSource so I gave it this update site: http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e3.6
and used selectAll , now it says cannot continue with installation becuase of some missing dependencies. 
so generally with an error like that how do you go back and find the things that needs to be installed first? and what are those in this particular question?

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: SpringSource Tool Suite Grails Support 2.6.0.201103161000-RELEASE (com.springsource.sts.grails.feature.group 2.6.0.201103161000-RELEASE)
  Missing requirement: SpringSource Tool Suite Grails Editor Support (Core) 2.6.0.201103161000-RELEASE (com.springsource.sts.grails.editor.groovy 2.6.0.201103161000-RELEASE) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: SpringSource Tool Suite Grails Support 2.6.0.201103161000-RELEASE (com.springsource.sts.grails.feature.group 2.6.0.201103161000-RELEASE)
    To: com.springsource.sts.grails.editor.groovy [2.6.0.201103161000-RELEASE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the Grails plugin?
http://dist.springsource.com/milestone/TOOLS/third-party/groovy-grails/e3.6

If you do not want Grails, unselect the checkbox Grails/Groovy checkbox.